# Evernote SDK - How can I get the permission to access all notebooks' metadata?

Tags: evernote

I'm writing a chrome extension for quick search notes in fuzzy match model. So I need to cache all notes' metadata(title, url, createdTime,etc) in local storage.

According to evernote offical doc, there are two ways to authenticate to the Evernote API, developer tokens and OAuth.
But right now, 
1. developer token has been deprecated.(if you go to the application URL you will get `Update: the creation of developer tokens is temporarily disabled.`
2. OAuth can only access one specific notebook(depend on user authentication)

So my question is : is there any way can work around to get all notes' metadata?

Comment: Why do you say the developer tokens are deprecated? I cannot get one as well, but did not see where it is stated that they are deprecated. May be there is just some maintenance is in the process? Anyway, I am also looking for the way to get developer token as well.

Comment: I got this yesterday too. Tweeted them, but haven't had a reply yet ... https://twitter.com/dracan/status/909082524818853888. Haven't tried it before, so I don't know whether it really is a tempory thing or not. Coincidence if it isn't that multiple people are suddenly complaining about it though - so I'm guessing it's temporary.

Comment: @prokher I send an email to their China support team, reply said they will stop supportting developer tokens soon since the security  issue, it's not recommanded right now. Although we have seperate account system in China( www.yinxiang.com ), I think the security policy would be the same.

Comment: @Dan Have any idea when OAuth can only access one notebook user authorized ?  I weakly remembered it's not like that before

Comment: @Damon.M Sorry, I've not used the Evernote SDK before. This was my first attempt, then wasn't able to create a token, so sent that message on Twitter. Googling the next day came across this SO thread. If they're not doing dev tokens anymore, then I'll have to give OAuth a go instead - so will find out when I get around to it. For my use-case, I'll only need to access one notebook anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2. OAuth can only access one specific notebook(depend on user authentication)

This is not the case. By default, Evernote API keys are scoped to the account level; so you'll have access to all notebooks in the account of the user who authenticates using your OAuth process.

Evernote does also have an optional type of API key available, called an [App Notebook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/app_notebook.php) key, that can be requested. But you have to specifically request that type of key when you request your API key; otherwise it'll be a full account access key.

Comment: Looks like I got an `App Notebook key`. This is weired, since I don't remember there's any checkbox to check. How could Evernote tell if I requested `App Notebook key` or something else, base on the `permissions` field in the request form?

Comment: You'll know it's an App Notebook key if, when you execute the OAuth process using that key, it prompts you to select a notebook.  If you're seeing that behavior, I'd recommend requesting another API key.  If you don't get that prompt, then you have a regular key for full-account access.

Comment: I got my evernote international api key activated today. All notebooks and notes can be accessed. It turns out yinxiang(evernote in China) has different authorizition policy, only App Notebook key is avaliable. For yinxiang, there's no way can access all notes' metadata, since developer key is canncelled.

Comment: Last question then I will close this issue. What happened to `Developer Tokens`? Will it be closed in future?

Comment: Developer Tokens were disabled as a precaution for something pending but I don't know what that something is - we'll have to wait for Evernote to provide more info on it.